# Simplify many like statements

Tags: pervasive

I have a list of names that are either a company name or a person's name. I have to manually decide if it's a company or a person. I have looked at each row and used a case to decide. If it's a company a one is placed. If it is a person, a zero is placed. Also, I have to parse the individual names into columns of first and last. There are 20 lines for each whe statements. It seems that pervasive can't handle all the statements. Am I doing this wrong? Is there a simpler way?

Example

`Own_name
Dollar Tree LLC
Jacob Smith
New Life Co
Johnson, Robert`

Here's a sample of what the SQL looks like:

`select
    CASE
    WHEN own_name LIKE '%co%' 
        OR own_name LIKE '%LLC%
    THEN 1 
    END AS is_compan, // if the own_name has Co or LLC, place a 1 in a column`

```
CASE
    WHEN own_name NOT LIKE '%co%' 
    OR own_name NOT LIKE '%LLC%
    THEN 0 
    END AS is_individual, //if the own_name DOES NOT have Co or LLC, place a 0 in a column
```

`CASE 
    WHEN locate(',', own_name)>0 
    AND own_name NOT LIKE '%co%' 
    AND own_name NOT LIKE '%LLC%' 
    THEN ltrim(left(own_name, locate(',', own_name)-1))`

```
   WHEN locate(' ', own_name)>0
   AND own_name NOT LIKE '%co%' 
   AND own_name NOT LIKE '%LLC%'
   THEN SUBSTRING(own_name, locate(' ', own_name) + 1, 8000) //if the own_name has a comma or a space and does not have CO or LLC in the column, parse the name for the last name
   END AS LAST_NAME
```

`CASE
    WHEN locate(',', own_name)>0 
    AND not locate('-', own_name)<0
    AND own_name NOT LIKE '%co%' 
    AND own_name NOT LIKE '%LLC%' 
   THEN ltrim(left(own_name, locate(',', own_name)-1))`

```
   WHEN locate(',', own_name)=0
   AND own_name NOT LIKE '%corp%' 
   AND own_name NOT LIKE '%LLC%' 
   THEN Ltrim(SubString(own_name,1,Isnull(Nullif(locate(' ',own_name),0),1000))) //if the own_name has a comma or a space and does not have CO or LLC in the column, parse the name for the first name
   END AS First_name
```

The result

`Own_name             is_compan    is individual  Last name     First name
Dollar Tree LLC       1

Jacob Smith                        0              Smith         Jacob
New Life Co           1

Johnson, Robert                    0              Johnson       Robert`

Comment: What version of Pervasive are you using?  What does "It seems that pervasive can't handle all the statements" mean?  Is it slow/?  It it giving an error?  
Your logic for company vs person is flawed.  What happens if you have a company without an LLC or CO in the name?  WHat happens if you have a person named "Cody"?  What's your full table structure look like?  Is there another way to determine if it's a company or person?

Comment: Version 12.11. Pervasive is continually running the query and does not produce a result. I know that there are cases that occur like Cody and Co. This is just a simple example about what I want to do. I basically want to know if there is a simpler way than to write a bunch or OR and AND statements.

Comment: With all of the LIKE and LOCATE calls, PSQL can't optimize on an index.  It might be faster to get the entire dataset and then parse it at the application level.